# Recover files from disk image

Tags: fedora, data-recovery, luks, disk-image

I had backed up `/dev/mapper/luks-....` (since I use FDE) using `dd`:

```shell
sudo dd if=/dev/mapper/luks-... of=backup.img
```

I don't seem to be able to access or restore the files. I have tried both mounting the `.img` and restoring to `/dev/mapper/luks-...` using `dd`, but the filesystem inside the `.img` seems to be corrupted.

Are there any ways to recover the data from the `.img`?

Comment: That depends on what's inside the image... which filesystem or other? For example if it's LVM on LUKS, you have to handle LVM first before you can mount anything.

Comment: It is not a LVM. I've tried checking the btrfs filesystem, but it seems corrupted.

Comment: Was the filesystem in use (mounted and/or LUKS opened) when you backed it up? I can't be completely sure from the partial `dd` command: did you backup the physical encrypted layer or the LUKS decrypted layer? What flags, if any, did you give to your `dd` command for the backup? Have you previously validated that your backup process works?

Comment: Yes, the filesystem was in use as it was mounted and I backed up the decrypted layer. No additional flags were used.